# How to open files from Google Drive in Python for a Telegram bot without downloading any files to your local computer or uploading from it?

Tags: python, download, google-drive-api, upload, telegram-bot

I'm making a Telegram bot, which retrieves a xlsx file from Google Drive and displays the information in the bot. I want to host the bot on a server, uploading files from a particular computer seems to be difficult. There are 2 problems. The first problem is during the process of authorization. There is a method of using Google Drive API, where you need to upload the json file with your credentials to connect to the drive. But where to store that file, if your code is on a server? Another problem is in saving the file. I've seen it multiple times, when the file from the drive is downloaded to your computer and only then opened in Python.
So, is there a way to authorize to Google Drive without using the previously saved file with the credentials on your local device and to open the file from the drive directly in Python, without saving it somewhere else?

Comment: Read [using oauth2.0 for server-to-server integration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The idea of my project is that when teachers edit the table with the school timetable (I used Google Drive as a place of storing this file), students can get up-to-date timetables for their grades via Telegram bot. The program downloads this file from the Google Drive and views it in Python. But there is a problem with using Google Drive, as I've explained above.  Has anyone made a similar project using files for Telegram bots? Have you maybe used not Google Drive, but other platform for storing the file online?